# Как удалить символы

Tags: php, while

Здраствуйте! Я получаю с помощью цикла while элементы из папок. При получение появляються сторонние символы (или так должно быть) . Мне нужно их удалить. Помогите мне с этим.[image: Вот]

```
     $pat = $_GET['p'];

    if($handle=opendir($pat)){
        while(($item = readdir($handle)) !== false)  {

}
```

Comment: это не сторонние символы, а текущая директория и предыдущая, они обозначаються как одна точка и две соответсвенно.

Comment: я понял но они мне не нужны и я хочу их удалить

Comment: @Anonim Anonim цикл свой листаните в вопросе.

Comment: Читайте документацию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readdir.php Пример номер 2.